# Is there a function in ruby to display from date to date in words?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the followings dates,

1. from_date( 11-15-2013) and to_date(11-30-2013)
2. from_date( 11-30-2013) and to_date(12-15-2013)

Now I wanted to display it in words lets say

```
Nov. 15 - 30, 2013
Nov. 30 - Dec. 15, 2013
```

is there existing ruby date class method to do this?

Comment: have you look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime ?

Comment: thanks for the answers.. I Get it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have:

```
date_str = "11-15-2013"
```

where you know the date format is "mm-dd-yyyy". Then the first step is to convert `date_str`to date a object, using the class method [Date::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime):

```
require 'date'

date_obj = Date.strptime(date_str, '%m-%d-%Y')
  #=> #<Date: 2013-11-15 ((2456612j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

We now use various methods in the [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) class to extract the information of interest:

```
month = date_obj.month #=> 11
day   = date_obj.day   #=> 15
year  = date_obj.year  #=> 2013
wday  = date_obj.wday  #=> 5
```

The date class also provides some useful constants, including:

```
Date::MONTHNAMES
  #=> [nil, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  #    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES
  #=> [nil, "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
  #    "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"] 

Date::DAYNAMES
 #=> ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
```

Note that the first elements of `Date::MONTHNAMES` and `Date::ABBT_MONTHNAMES` (`nil`) are never referenced because January is month `1`, not month `0`.

We can now construct strings such as the following:

```
"Today is day #{day} of #{Date::MONTHNAMES[month]}, a #{Date::DAYNAMES[wday]}."
  #=> "Today is day 15 of November, a Friday." 

"Oh, I forgot, the year is #{year}." 
  #=> "Oh, I forgot, the year is 2013.
```

So doing what you want to do is a fairly straightforward application of these methods:

```
require 'date'

def spell_out_date_ranges(*date_ranges)
  date_ranges.map { |start_str, end_str|
    spell_out_one_range(start_str, end_str) }.join(' ')
end 

def spell_out_one_range(start_str, end_str)
   sd = date_str_to_hash(start_str)
   ed = date_str_to_hash(end_str)
   if sd[:month] == ed[:month] && sd[:year] == ed[:year]
     "%s. %d - %d, %d" % [sd[:month_name], sd[:day], ed[:day], sd[:year]]
   elsif sd[:year] == ed[:year]
     "%s. %d - %s. %d, %d" % [sd[:month_name], sd[:day], ed[:month_name],
       ed[:day], sd[:year]]
   else
     "%s. %d, %d - %s. %d, %d" % [sd[:month_name], sd[:day], sd[:year],
       sd[:month_name], ed[:day], ed[:year]]
   end
 end

def date_str_to_hash(date_str)
  d = Date.strptime(date_str, '%m-%d-%Y')
  { day: d.day, month: d.month, month_name: Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[d.month],
    year: d.year }
end
```

Let's try it:

```
spell_out_date_ranges(['11-15-2013', '11-30-2013'], ['11-30-2013', '12-15-2013'],
                      ['11-30-2013', '12-15-2014'])
  #=> "Nov. 15 - 30, 2013 Nov. 30 - Dec. 15, 2013 Nov. 30, 2013 - Nov. 15, 2014"
```

Here I've used the method [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) to format the strings. The format syntax is explained in the doc for the method [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Answer (score 0):

No ruby date class method can make it directly, you should do something by yourself. you can use `strftime` method format the time.

```
Date.new(2015,12,30).strftime("%b") # get The abbreviated month name 
=> "Dec"
Date.new(2015,12,30).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") # get the year, month, day
=> "2015-12-30"
Date.parse("30-12-2015") # convert string to date
=> Wed, 30 Dec 2015
```

you can make it like this:

```
def func(date1, date2)
  date1, date2 = date2, date1 if date1 > date2
  if date1.year == date2.year and date1.month == date2.month
    return [date1.strftime("%b.%d"), date2.strftime("%d,%Y")].join('-')
  elsif date1.year == date2.year and date1.month != date2.month
    return [date1.strftime("%b.%d"), date2.strftime("%b.%d,%Y")].join('-')
  elsif date1.year != date2.year
    return [date1.strftime("%b.%d,%Y"), date2.strftime("%b.%d,%Y")].join('-')
  end
end

func(Date.new(2015,11,15), Date.new(2015,11,30))
=> "Nov.15-30,2015"
func(Date.new(2015,11,15), Date.new(2015,12,30))
=> "Nov.15-Dec.30,2015"
func(Date.new(2014,11,15), Date.new(2015,12,30))
=> "Nov.15,2014-Dec.30,2015"
```